# resize() fail when i pass newSize parameter in open cv

Tags: android, opencv

In android i am trying to scale my mat using following code.

```
Mat destMat = new Mat(); 
Size newSize=new Size(output.width()/6.0f, output.height()/6.0f); 
Imgproc.resize(output, destMat, newSize, 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);
```

When it try to execute the resize method i get following exception. My code is in onCameraFrame().

> MatToBitmap catched cv::Exception:
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97:
>   error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows &&
>   info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void
>   Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong,
>   jobject, jboolean)

Answer (score 0):

Where the variable 'newSize' is, you actually want the original size of destMat. You can scale it down by using the fx and fy parameters. From the javadocs:

> The function resize resizes the image src down to or up to the
>   specified size.Note that the initial dst type or size are not taken
>   into account. Instead, the size and type are derived from the
>   src,dsize,fx, and fy.

Later on:

> // explicitly specify dsize=dst.size(); fx and fy will be computed
>   from that.